# Probability of Intersection of Union of Events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to show the following:

Let $C_1,C_2...$ be a sequence of events such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(C_n)=0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(C_{n+1} \setminus C_n) < \infty$. Show that $P(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}\cup_{k=n}^{\infty}C_k)=0.$

Not sure where to start here.

Answer (score 1):

First we have
$$
\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}C_k=C_n\cup\bigcup_{k=n+1}^{\infty}C_k=C_n\cup\bigcup_{k=n+1}^{\infty}(C_k-\bigcup_{i=n}^{k-1}C_i)\subset C_n\cup\bigcup_{k=n+1}^{\infty}(C_k-C_{k-1})
$$
last step holds for $\bigcup_{i=n}^{k-1}C_i\supset C_{k-1}$.

In addition, given condition implies that for large $n$ there is
$$
P(C_n)<\epsilon\quad\text{ and }\quad \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}P(C_k-C_{k-1})<\epsilon
$$
Hence
\begin{align}
P\left(\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}C_k\right)&\leqslant P(C_n)+P\left(\bigcup_{k=n+1}^{\infty}(C_k-C_{k-1})\right)
\\
&\leqslant P(C_n) +\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}P(C_k-C_{k-1})
\\
&<2\epsilon
\end{align}
Since for any $n$
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}C_k\subset \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}C_k
$$
We have
$$
P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}C_k\right)\leqslant P\left(\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}C_k\right) <2\epsilon 
$$
By arbitrariness of $\epsilon$,  we conclude
$$
P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}C_k\right)=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$P\bigcap_{n \ge 1} \bigcup_{k \ge n} C_k = \lim_{n \to \infty} P \bigcup_{k \ge n} C_k
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(P(C_n) + \sum_{k > n}P(C_k \setminus C_{k-1})\right).$$

Make sure you can justify each step.